# Can't Run GTK on WSL, Display Error

Tags: xorg, gtk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL on Windows 10. I've installed `gtkwave` through the terminal, but I am unable to run it. My system gives me the following error:

```
Could not initialize GTK!  Is DISPLAY env var/xhost set?
```

I've tried installing `xhost`, but running `xhost +LOCAL:` only gives this error:

```
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
```

How can I fix this and run GTK GUIs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WSL doesn't come with an X server by default, because Windows doesn't use an X server. Which would also be why `xhost` failed to do anything remotely useful.

In order to do something like this, you need to download an X server for Windows, and then configure that. For example, you can use the [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) project to run a display server. When launching Xming, you can use the `-multiwindow` option to make it so you don't have a virtual desktop. However, this may not be the case with other X servers present on Windows.

You can find a quick tutorial [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3055403/windows/windows-10s-bash-shell-can-run-graphical-linux-applications-with-this-trick.html) for Xming specifically (really, it's just install + configure + `export DISPLAY=:0`) or [here](https://ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-x-on-wsl?ts=sb) also for Xming. Alternatively you can use MobaXTerm ([tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182483/how-to-use-x-windows-with-emacs-on-windows-10-bash)), which will achieve the same basic result.

In short, find an X server you like, and install it on Windows. After that, your WSL instance should be able to pick up on the fact that an X server is available, and you should be able to run GUI-based programs without much hassle.

Comment: thanks for the reply ,i ran mobaxterm and then set the Displayport `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` ,then GTK worked .thanks again :)

Comment: @namila007 No problem! Oh, by the way, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I hope you enjoy your stay here. Might I also suggest you visit our [tour]? It's a great way for new users to get quickly familiarized with the site, and to get a free badge.

Comment: thanks,sure im gonna stay here coz i started using ubuntu(kubuntu) recently . i already visited it .thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, WSL should be able to run GTK software. If not, try updating your WSL from cmd/powershell.

```
wsl --update
```