# Gnuplot display on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

Windows 10 Anniversary Update contains a Linux subsystem. I am in need of working in a Linux environment so I began looking into this subsystem. So far, I have been able to install all the needed applications. I successfully installed gnuplot and it runs just fine. However, I cannot set `term` to `x11`, and therefore I cannot plot anything to display. Following is the error:

```
Terminal type set to 'qt'
gnuplot> set term x11
Terminal type set to 'x11'
Options are ' nopersist enhanced'
gnuplot>
gnuplot: unable to open display ''
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

I tried installing Xming onto the same directory as the Bash program lies in Windows, but no luck. I really need gnuplot, and even though I can install it on Windows, it would be much more convenient to have it on the Linux subsystem.

How can I fix this display/x11(forwarding) issue?

Comment: Not sure that Windows Linux subsystem is Ubuntu?

Comment: Its a Linux subsystem and it runs Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS according to lsb_release -a

Comment: Related: [Can't Run GTK on WSL, Display Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Install Xming.
(2) execute `export DISPLAY=:0 nameOfProgram` (for example `export DISPLAY=:0 gnuplot`

Answer (score 0):

Another (open source!) x server is VcXsrv. You can enable ANY graphical application (not only gnuplot) for WSL.

In summary:

- install VcXsrv (https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)
- launch xlaunch.exe (e.g. in "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\xlaunch.exe"). You should pay extra attention to the following options during configuration:

  - set "Multiple Windows" (will make windows appear like you're used to)
  - add "-ac" to the "Additional parameters for VcXsrv" (will make the x server accessible for your WSL)
  - at the end, save the configuration file to your start-up applications (%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup)
- add "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" to the end of your "~/.bashrc"

If you would further like to run e.g. 'gnuplot -p script', you should set the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR environment variable for the corresponding temporary storage. Add

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/an/appropriate/dir
export RUNLEVEL=3
```

to your ~/.bashrc, where "an/appropriate/dir" can be something like "runtime-" + your user name.

Sources:

- https://www.stat.ipb.ac.id/agusms/index.php/2019/01/15/how-to-run-graphical-linux-applications-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/
- https://superuser.com/questions/1476086/error-cant-open-display-0
- https://seanthegeek.net/234/graphical-linux-applications-bash-ubuntu-windows/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790350/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-aadithyasb