# Gnuplot on Ubuntu from Microsoft Store, can't open x11 window

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

I can't run gnuplot x11 terminal from Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft Store. I installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Store, then I installed VcXsrv. Then I run Xlaunch (VcXsrv) - choose display settings multiple windows, Start no client (I also tried with parameter -ac), then I choose Clipboard, Primary selection and native opengpl and finish. Then I run Ubuntu from Microsoft Store on terminal write  `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` then `gnuplot` then `set terminal x11` and I get error
Terminal type is now 'x11'
Options are ' nopersist enhanced'
gnuplot>
gnuplot: unable to open display 'localhost:0.0'
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
Why?
[image]

I try to do this like here but it doesn't work
[Gnuplot display on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948830/gnuplot-display-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify, but it sounds like you are running WSL2.  The post you linked to was from over 4 years ago when only WSL1 existed.  They are quite different.

While WSL1 shared the same network as the Windows host, WSL2 uses a virtual network that is NAT'd *behind* the Windows host, inside part of the Hyper-V subsystem.

As a result, attempting to connect to `localhost` won't work, since `localhost` isn't the Windows host.

Instead, use:

```
export DISPLAY="$(hostname).local:0.0"
```

That uses the mDNS name of the Windows host to obtain the correct IP, which usually works. If not, there are more complicated `export DISPLAY` strings that can be tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. It works, I also got an error:

```
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

gnuplot: unable to open display 'DESKTOP-U0BQ8NT.local:0.0'
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

Something like that https://superuser.com/questions/1174563/when-trying-to-connect-remote-clients-to-cygwin-x-i-get-authorization-required

but I turn on turn on "Disable access control" setting and it works right now.