# How do I install the alarm-clock-applet in WSL Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to install and setup the WSL Ubuntu 18.04 alarm-clock-applet. I'm new to Linux and haven't ever done this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software provided in software-center via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268504/how-to-install-software-provided-in-software-center-via-terminal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Run GTK on WSL, Display Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: Old question that has been twice bumped by Community Bot.  After chat discussions, I've been convinced that this particular question deserves its own answer, separate from the ones I linked in my original "duplicate" flags.

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was asked, the options for doing this were fairly limited.  It would have been possible to *run* `alarm-clock-applet` on WSL1 using a third-party X server on Windows such as VcXsrv as detailed in some of the answers found in [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986).  And technically, that would answer the question as it was asked.

However, there's almost certainly more to the question than just that, and that's what probably makes it an [XY problem question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/902710).  *Why* did you need the alarm clock applet?  It's unlikely that you needed an alarm clock with notifications, since that's built into Windows anyway.

When the question was asked, anyway, it wouldn't have been easy to get notifications when alarms went off under WSL1.  The applet would have run, but without Gnome Desktop running, there wouldn't have been any "receiver" to display the notifications.

And getting Gnome Desktop wouldn't have been easy under WSL1 since it utilizes Systemd to run many of its dependencies.  Regardless, this would have probably been overkill just to run an alarm clock applet.

For the last few years, it's been *possible* to run Gnome Desktop under WSL2 using the method I cover in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986).  The Alarm Clock applet does work there (at least in Ubuntu 18.04).  Again, probably overkill ...

Finally, it's probably possible to create a service that listens for the D-Bus notifications when an alarm sounds and display these through something like:

- Tmux display-message
- A pts message
- Or even a Windows toast notification using WSL's Interop features

Answer (score 0):

Actualy it's quite simple.

Just use software app from application menu

[image: ubuntu software]

search for `alarm-clock-applet` and install it.

Alternatively you can do this via terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alarm-clock-applet
```

To open terminal go to `Applications menu` and type `terminal` or press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Find more about terminal here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: I'm using WSL Ubuntu brought up through a PowerShell window and don't see any icon, just the command line. I didn't know menus were available. If you'd be so kind as to point me at documentation or could provide some I would be most grateful. I will, of course, be doing the terminal thing and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about such way of using ubuntu, but you can either try to use `sudo apt install alarm-clock-applet`. From a quick research about WSL - it should work. If it's not, try to enable universe repository like so: `sudo apt-add-repository universe` before installing alarm-clock-applet.