# WSL: umake doesn't list pycharm

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ide, pycharm, ubuntu-make

The umake docs (both [online](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/umake.1.html) and on my ubuntu installation) say that `umake ide` has options including "pycharm,pycharm-educational,pycharm-professional". However when I try this on Ubuntu20 over WSL:

```
umake ide pycharm
```

I get -

```
 ... umake ide: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'pycharm'
(choose from 'arduino', 'atom', 'clion', 'dbeaver', 'datagrip',
'eclipse-cpp', 'eclipse-jee', 'eclipse-javascript', 'eclipse',
'eclipse-php', 'goland', 'idea', 'idea-ultimate', 'lighttable',
'netbeans', 'netbeans-html', 'netbeans-jee', 'phpstorm', 'processing',
'rider', 'rubymine', 'spring-tools-suite', 'sublime-text',
'visual-studio-code', 'webstorm')
```

As suggested by other answers here, I did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
```

With no success. Is this a known WSL issue? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *think* this is unique to WSL, but I might be wrong.  I can reproduce this with the `ubuntu-make` package available on 20.04 (on WSL), but it appears to be an issue with not detecting that Python is installed, perhaps due to the change to `python3`.

You can get more info with:

```
umake --list -vv
```

... which shows (among other lines) ...

```
INFO: python isn't installed
...
INFO: python isn't available on this platform
...
pycharm: PyCharm Community Edition [not installable on this machine]
```

I was able to solve this with the latest daily build.

Your question shows you doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
```

But you don't show a corresponding:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

... that would be critical to actually *upgrade* the package.

If you didn't `upgrade`, do that and see if it works.

If you did upgrade, then try the latest daily (as noted in the [ubuntu-make Github readme](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make)) which worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-make
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Also, you don't mention what Windows version you are using or if you have other Linux GUI applications working.  If you are using Windows 10, you'll need to configure GUI app support with either:

- `xrdp` as I mention in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986)
- A third-party XServer as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1580614/1210833)

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!  I'm using windows11 and didn't have problems in the past with gui apps. Will revisit your advice if I do.

Comment: @OfekShilon Right - It shouldn't be a problem with Windows 11; just wasn't sure if you were using 10 or 11.

Comment: @OfekShilon And don't forget to Accept the answer so that this gets closed out.  Thanks!