# Running DejaDup/Installing ubuntu-desktop Issues

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, deja-dup

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10.  Running uname -r returns: 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2.  I am trying to run deja-dup, but am having no luck.    When I try kicking it off from a Ubuntu terminal, I get the message:

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.DejaDup:29): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:01:49.822: cannot open display:

Searching for how to run it, it looks like most people kick it off using something called Dash (which I am not familiar with).  I do have something installed at /usr/bin/dash which when I run it get the following message: dash: 0: Bad substitution

It was awhile ago since I installed Ubuntu, but I don't believe I did anything to it to run apps with a GUI.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Based on the comment to add notes on what I did to allow Ubuntu to run apps with a GUI, I just now did a search and tried the following: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gui-installation

I got to step 6 where it said to do a reboot, but that failed due to:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

So, I tried starting it via startx.  When doing that, I got an error:
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server

I found that I could update the file Xwrapper.config in /etc/X11 from allowed_users=console to allowed_users=anybody.

Now when I run startx, I get:
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1413718/edit) and add the following information: Are you using WSL1 or WSL2? Have you done any modification to the WSL Ubuntu installation so that it can run apps with a GUI? If so, list the exact procedure you used in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL on Windows 10 does not have any ability to run GUI applications (including an X server itself).  If you don't have any other data in Ubuntu/WSL, I'd probably uninstall and reinstall, since you have a lot of unnecessary packages by following the instructions you linked.

You have three main options for running GUI applications under WSL:

- Upgrade to Windows 11, where WSL2 *does* have the built-in ability to run GUI applications using the WSLg feature.
- Use a third-party X server in *Windows* (not Ubuntu).
- Access Ubuntu through `xrdp` using the Remote Desktop client in Windows.

You'll find more details on these options in several questions:

- Here on Ask Ubuntu: [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986)
- Super User:  [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833)

As for trying to run Ubuntu Desktop on WSL2, I recommend that you do not for answers you'll find in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986).  You don't need a Linux desktop in WSL (Windows is your desktop); just an X or Wayland server.  If you feel the need for one, try Xfce4 since it does not have the Systemd dependency that Gnome does.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I really appreciate it.