# Cannot start gnome-session after enabling Systemd on latest WSL2

Tags: gnome, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.01 on WSL2 on Windows 11 22H2 with Systemd support. However, though I've followed all the instructions mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432937/how-to-install-gnome-for-ubuntu-22-04-on-wsl2), I still can't start `gnome-session` properly. It only shows an "Oh no! something went wrong!" sign like this.

[image]

I checked the logs and saw the following messages, not sure if it is relevant:

```
misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -2
```

Answer (score 1):

**i) CONFIGURE WINDOWS**

- First, update Windows to the latest version.
- Then Install 2022-11 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 10 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5020030)
- Check that your OS build is at least 19045.2311. If the second part after the period is < 2311, then you have not installed the preview and nothing will work properly. This step is crucial to get WSLg working properly.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2

- Go to control panel->programs->turn windows features on or off. Make sure Virtual Machine Platform is checked on.
- Go to your BIOS. Make sure virtualization is enabled in BIOS (on AMD it is called SVM)

**ii) CONFIGURE UBUNTU ON WSL**

- add to /etc/wsl.conf

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

- Create the file /etc/pam.d/system/systemd-user

```
# This file is part of systemd.
#
# Used by systemd --user instances.

@include common-account

session  required pam_loginuid.so
session  required pam_limits.so
@include common-session-noninteractive
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

- Stop WSL with "wsl --shutdown" and then restart with "wsl"
- `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop acpi-support-`

ubuntu-desktop tries to install acpi-support. This will literally brick your distro to an unrecoverable state, yielding a catastrophic error when you attempt to run WSL. Do not forget to add the "-" sign to tell apt to ignore this dependency otherwise you'll have to delete the distro and reinstall.

- `sudo systemctl stop gdm.service`

Failure to prevent gdm running will cause all sorts of errors when you try to run a gnome-shell.

- `sudo systemctl disable gdm.service`
- Add the following to the system startup - it needs to be executed with elevated privileges. I enabled systemd's rc-local compatibility service and then added them to /etc/rc.local. Just be sure to chmod 700 /etc/rc.local

```
mount -o rw,remount /tmp/.X11-unix/
chmod +t /tmp/.X11-unix
chmod o+rw /dev/dri/renderD128
/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-immediately &
```

- Stop WSL with "wsl --shutdown" and then restart with "wsl"
- Add the following to your .bashrc

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 gnome-session --disable-acceleration-check --session=ubuntu --systemd-service > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- Now run gnome-shell with the following command. Adapt the resolution to your preference.

```
MUTTER_DEBUG_DUMMY_MODE_SPECS=2400x1300 gnome-shell --nested --no-x11 2> /dev/null &
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Voq.png)

Comment: In my case, it did not work when running the boot script mentioned above. Additionally, when removing the `--disable-acceleration-check` argument from the XDG_SESSION_TYPE variable, the performance was smoother. Furthermore, the entire value of the XDG_SESSION_TYPE had to be enclosed in single quotes like so: `XDG_SESSION_TYPE='x11 gnome-session --disable-acceleration-check --session=ubuntu --systemd-service > /dev/null 2>&1'` as otherwise the output redirection would happen during the login script, not the start of the session.