# How do I fix the errors I'm getting while trying to install/run GNOME?

Tags: gnome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using wsl (wsl2 I believe). I have GNOME installed, but Ubuntu will not boot into it. I have tried using the line `sudo reboot` like the guide says to do, but I got this error message.

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon
```

I have no clue what to do here as nothing I can find referring to installing GNOME mentions any of these errors. What should I do here?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which WSL is being used, as no amount of effort will give you a workable GUI with WSL1. Typing `wsl -l -v` into command prompt or Power Shell will provide this info 

Comment: @matigo That will usually just tell which Ubuntu distribution is being used under WSL (but may not even be accurate).  `wsl --version` will give us a better indicator.  The command may not be found, in which case we know it's an older (pre-Systemd) release.  But if it is there, it should return the actual WSL (and Windows) version info.  Then a normal `cat /etc/os-release` for the distro info.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu HightlyHylian.  There are a few questions that address this topic already here. [Opening Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252007/opening-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-on-wsl2) is one way, and [Cannot start gnome-session after enabling Systemd on latest WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1442663/1165986) is another.

Comment: Also see [System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate](https://askubuntu.com/q/1379425/1165986) to understand and fix the root problem.  Thanks!