# Can't launch Gnome desktop from Ubuntu terminal running under WSL2

Tags: command-line, gnome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've gone through the process of installing WSL2 on a Windows 11 laptop and can successfully run, for example, GUI-type LibreOffice apps from the Terminal command line.

So far, so good.

Now I would like to try using Gnome.

I've installed Gnome desktop using:

`sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop`

... but after rebooting I get messages such as:

```
<3>WSL (1408) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2671: Failed to translate C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Comment: A quick search brings up this Microsoft web site. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9360

Answer (score 1):

WSL is not made to run a full Linux Desktop environment, but it can run single graphical applications in a single window.

If you are looking for installing and running a complete Ubuntu desktop on Windows with minimal effort, take a look at [Multipass](https://multipass.run/) from Canonical and add a [Desktop enviroment](https://multipass.run/docs/set-up-a-graphical-interface#heading--using-rdp) to the base installation.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you mention seems unrelated to you trying to run Ubuntu Desktop under WSL.

That error is typically caused by a combination of:

- Upgrading to a recent release of WSL
- A directory that doesn't exist being in your *Windows* path.

In Ubuntu:

```
powershell.exe -c '$env:PATH' | tr ';' '\n'
```

- Look for a directory in that list that doesn't exist in Windows.
- Go to the *Edit the system environment variables* Windows setting
- Press the *Environment Variables* button

Remove the bad directory from the `PATH` variable.  This might be under either your user or the System variable list.

---

And while I don't necessarily recommend it, for information on running Ubuntu Desktop in Ubuntu on WSL, see the following questions:

- [Opening Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252007/1165986)
- [Cannot start gnome-session after enabling Systemd on latest WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1442663/1165986)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked all those path directories and they do indeed exist. I've decided not to try installing Ubuntu desktop. I was under misapprehension that that came naturally with WSL2. Don't need it