# How to install Gnome for Ubuntu 22.04.1 on WSL2 on Windows 11 with built-in Systemd support?

Tags: gnome, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 from the Microsoft Store on WSL2 on my Windows 11 machine which now [supports Systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/), and I'm trying to install Gnome. All the instructions I've found show how to install Gnome by enabling Systemd. I'm looking for instructions [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/866221) based on Gnome which doesn't require enabling Systemd.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  While I've made some edits to your question, it's still not exactly clear.  You mention that you are running the updated WSL2 which supports Systemd, but you are *"looking for instructions [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/866221) based on Gnome which doesn't require enabling Systemd."*  While that's my answer, it *does* require Systemd.  Are you just looking for instructions that work on 22.04 with the *built-in* WSL2 Systemd support?  It still requires *enabling* Systemd, of course ...

Comment: Or are you truly asking for a Gnome installation that doesn't require Systemd?  If so, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), specifically - *"Gnome is also an application (ecosystem) that is very tightly coupled with Systemd, but it's popular enough that there have been ports to non-Systemd init systems. That said, running it on Ubuntu does assume the presence of Systemd, so you would have to reverse-engineer the process used on those other distributions if you wanted to run it on Ubuntu/WSL without the use of Systemd."*