# Error when running tkinter in python " no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" while running the code

Tags: python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tkinter

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2261, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: WSL is a CLI environment - for WSL1 see [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux as of 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018). WSL2 is somewhat different [How to set up working X11 forwarding on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110603/how-to-set-up-working-x11-forwarding-on-wsl2)

Comment: While support for Xorg is a planned feature for WSL, and support for GUI applications is planned some time after that, it's still unsupported.  Please see the WSL FAQ on the topic: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Comment: Community Bot auto-bumped this question today, since it has no accepted answers.  However, it's really a duplicate of *many* questions here.  I'll start with [Can't Run GTK on WSL, Display Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error).  I'd recommend closing this so that it doesn't get auto-bumped again.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of WSL2 has built-in support for GUI apps on Linux.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps?source=recommendations)

> **Existing WSL install**
>
> If you already have WSL installed on your
> machine, you can update to the latest version that includes Linux GUI
> support by running the update command from an elevated command prompt.
>
> Select Start, type PowerShell, right-click Windows PowerShell, and
> then select Run as administrator.
>
> Enter the WSL update command:
>
> ```
> wsl --update
> ```
>
> You will need to restart WSL for the update to take
> effect. You can restart WSL by running the shutdown command in
> PowerShell.
>
> ```
> wsl --shutdown
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me was to `export DISPLAY=:0`, or `export DISPLAY=:0.0` may work also.
If either of those work, add them to ~/.profile to make it persistent.